# Confirm Window in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, confirm

I have this following code :

```
renderPosts() {
return _.map(this.state.catalogue, (catalogue, key) => {
  return (
    <div className="item col-md-3" key={key} id={key}>
        <img src={this.state.catalogue[key].avatarURL} height={150} with={150}/>
        <h3>{catalogue.marque}</h3>
        <h4>{catalogue.numero}</h4>
        <h4>{catalogue.reference}</h4>
        <p>{catalogue.cote}</p>
        <div className="text-center">
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => {if(window.confirm('Delete the item?')){this.removeToCollection.bind(this, key)};}}>Supprimer</button>
        </div>

    </div>
  )
 })
}
```

And I have this function too:

```
removeToCollection(key, e) {

  const item = key;
  firebase.database().ref(`catalogue/${item}`).remove();
 }
```

When I use the function without a confirm window in my "onclick" button, the code work great. But when I want use a confirm window, the confirm window show when I click on my button, but my item is not delete.

Any idea ?

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Basically you're binding the function instead of calling it... you should bind beforehand, preferably in the constructor... then call it.
Try this:

```js
renderPosts() {
  this.removeToCollection = this.removeToCollection.bind(this);
  return _.map(this.state.catalogue, (catalogue, key) => {
    return (
      <div className="item col-md-3" key={key} id={key}>
          <img src={this.state.catalogue[key].avatarURL} height={150} with={150}/>
          <h3>{catalogue.marque}</h3>
          <h4>{catalogue.numero}</h4>
          <h4>{catalogue.reference}</h4>
          <p>{catalogue.cote}</p>
          <div className="text-center">
          <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => {if(window.confirm('Delete the item?')){this.removeToCollection(key, e)};}}>Supprimer</button>
          </div>

      </div>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: I wish it didn't have a syntax error in the code snippet to be able to see the result.

Answer (score 13):

**You are just binding function and not calling it.**

The right synatx to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and called `bind`ed function.

```
if (window.confirm("Delete the item?")) {
    let removeToCollection = this.removeToCollection.bind(this, 11);//bind will return to reference to binded function and not call it.
    removeToCollection();
}
```

OR you can do like this as well without bind.

```
if (window.confirm("Delete the item?")) {
  this.removeToCollection(11);
}
```

If **this** is concern inside `removeToCollection` then use [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to define it.

```
removeToCollection=(key)=> {
    console.log(key);
  }
```

Working [`codesandbox demo`](https://codesandbox.io/s/k0nl6871xr)

Answer (score 7):

I did the same as below-

> I have a smart(class) component

```
<Link to={`#`} onClick={() => {if(window.confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?')){ this.deleteHandler(item.id)};}}> <i className="material-icons">Delete</i> </Link>
```

I defined a function to call the delete endpoint as-

```
deleteHandler(props){
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/product?id=${props}`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('Deleted Successfully.');
    })
  }
```

And that worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

```
window.confirm();
```

truly works.
Dont know why confirm(); alone doesn't work on react